# Regex for name String matching. (JAVA)

Tags: java, regex

I am wanting to write a regular expression that will match any String that contains the name. Though it has some restrictions when matching with a String.

**Rule: The first letter of each String is the only letter that can be capital.**

Valid names are:
Samuel,
Samuel Fosters,
Samuel Johnson Fosters

Invalid names are:
samuel,
samuel Fosters,
Samuel fosters,
SamuelFosters

This is the regex that I have written so far:

```
"[A-Z][a-z]|[A-Z][a-z]+(\\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+"
```

I am getting true for all the valid names, but it is also returning true for the invalid cases.

How would I edit the regex so that it returns false for the invalid names while returning true for the valid names?

Comment: Try this - `^([A-Z][a-z]+)(\\s[A-Z][a-z]+)?$`

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What are the exact rules? What is the base alphabet? Are there any time constraints on the regex?

Comment: Well now this becomes really complicated when there aren't rules... For example. You say that you want to match strings that *contain* a name - this means that other text accompanies the names. What makes `Samuel` acceptable, but not `Samuel fosters`? In the second example, is matching `Samuel` acceptable? If not, what happens if your sentence is `Samuel fosters children`? Do abbreviations exist? Do initials exist (`Samuel L. Jackson`)? Do any other characters exist in names `.-'é`? Do other proper names exist (`New York`)? Are one-letter names allowed `Mr. T.`? What are the rules???

Comment: Just some lecture: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 0):

The regex written is `[A-Z][a-z]`.

Generalizing to cap first words separated by single whitespace is

`"^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:\\s[A-Z][a-z]+)*$"`

https://regex101.com/r/sa88TU/1

Comment: I'll say same thing here as on Matt's answer - There isn't nearly enough information to propose an answer...

Comment: Like comments without information, there is never enough information.

Answer (score -1):

Try Regex: `(?<=^|, )\b[A-Z][a-z][a-z]+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)*(?=,|$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8J6eWq/1)

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information to propose an answer...